# Sulla giusta coniugazione del verbo "riempire"

Tags: verbs

Salve, mi è venuto un dubbio sulla coniugazione del verbo riempire. In effetti pensavo che al congiuntivo presente 3ª persona si scrivesse:

> (che) egli **riempa**

tuttavia mentre scrivevo il correttore del PC mi ha segnalato come errore tale scrittura, suggerendomi la corretta:

> (che) egli **riempia**

Ora in effetti non mi suona sbagliato, tuttavia mi è venuto il dubbio che la forma senza la `i` sia un lascito magari del dialetto toscano o che esista anch'essa a fianco di quella corretta (pur non avendone trovato traccia on-line).

Così come nel presente, si può dire sia

> egli **riempe**

che

> egli **riempie**

o la prima è sbagliata? Sapete se per caso sia un uso dialettale o magari solo un po' antiquato, o è da tacciarsi come errore?

Comment: Dovrei controllare in un dizionario per essere sicuro che non siano toscanismi ammessi come *spengere*, ma a me *riempe* e *riempa* suonano sbagliati.

Comment: Mai visto o sentito le forme senza “i”, né le riportano i dizionari. Ne hai consultato uno prima di porre qui la domanda?

Comment: No, ho visto solo on-line.

Comment: Ci sono buoni dizionari anche in rete, @opisthofulax. Abbiamo un [post sul Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-good-reference-works-on-italian-are-available-online) che elenca varie risorse. Fra i dizionari elencati lì, consiglio in particolare il Treccani, il Sabatini-Coletti e il De Mauro (quest'ultimo però non dà la coniugazione dei verbi).

Comment: Io da Toscana dico lui riempe e che riempa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il vocabolario Treccani online indica come riferimento la coniugazione del verbo "empire*. Per cui ***"che io riempia", non riempa:***

***[Riempire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riempire/)*** (non com. rïémpiere, ant. o poet. rémpiere) v. tr. [comp. di ri- e empire (o empiere)] (io rïémpio, ecc.; ***coniug. come empire).***

***[Empire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/empire)*** (o émpiere) v. tr. [lat. implēre, comp. di in- e plēre (usato solo in composizione e nei der.: cfr. plenus «pieno»)] (pres. indic. émpio, émpi, émpie, empiamo, empite, émpiono; ***pres. cong. émpia***.

I rari usi visibili su [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riempa%2C%20riempia%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Criempa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Criempia%3B%2Cc0) della forma "riempa" sembrano più errori di battitura che altro.

Comment: Forse questo "riempa" è una forma arcaica.

Comment: In effetti pensavo ad un arcaismo... Se avessi con me il Devoto-Oli avrei già verificato, di solito quel dizionario riporta sempre tali sottigliezze. Comunque grazie mille per Ngram, sito utilissimo!

Comment: Io ho sentito spesso la forma *riempe*, *riempa*, senza *i* . Questo sito, di un esperto che non conosco, parla di verbi *sovrabbondanti*, e dice che entrambe le forme sono possobili, ma non tutti i linguisti sono d'accordo: https://faustoraso.blogspot.com/2011/09/riempiendo-o-riempendo.html